# Conditional redirection with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am not happy with the way Pinterest references my photos, as the source mentionned in their page links directly to the JPEG image file instead of the page that contains it, that also includes the author reference and license information.

However instead of asking them to de-reference all the pictures, I'd like to keep them as it can be a good way to bring traffic in, but I would like to create a redirection from the JPEG image URL to the page that contains these elements.

Is there a way to do a conditional redirection with .htaccess if the link comes from an external server?

Thanks all !

Answer (score 0):

You may use the technique described here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/access.html#blocked-inline-images

Say your site is www.example.com and you want to redirect all request for jpeg images (eg image123.jpeg) not coming from your site, to the corresponding php page (eg /galleries/image123.php)

You can do that this way:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)\.(jpg|jpeg)$ /gallery/$1.php [R,NC]
```